# How to scroll by touch custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom control in a winforms C# application which looks like this:

```
    PANEL
    -label1
    -label2
    -label3
```

If I want to scroll with the mouse wheel, scrolls fine, even if I have the mouse over one of those labels. The problem comes when I want to scroll touching the screen.

If I touch the panel it scrolls just fine, but it doesn't if I touch over a label.

ps: actually labels are custom controls too.

Comment: WinForms events don't _bubble_ up to their containers.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Try search "bubble events WinForms". Many questions also here on SO. However I'm not sure you will really find an easy way to do it. I'd try to simply SendMessage() to container for mouse move and clicks. Easier (IMO) to do it on WndPrc of your labels (but don't forget that contained controls has to do that too...)